# Delete slow SQL Server table linked to Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access

I have a link from Microsoft Access to a SQL Server table.  The I/O is pretty good except when I tell it to delete some 1400 records.  It takes about 45 seconds to process through that.
If I issue the same delete command in SSMS, it runs instantaneously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run it as a [pass-through query](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968)

Comment: ...the reason for that is that Jet/ACE tries to be a good "database server citizen" and instead of sending a SQL batch delete, it sends a separate SQL delete for each row being deleted. This allows the server to interleave the delete operation with commands from other users of the server, but it means the deletion is really slow for the end user. With a passthrough, you're telling the server to process it as a batch delete, instead of letting Jet/ACE convert your SQL DELETE into something you didn't intend.

Comment: (Way) more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Pass-through queries are so fast.... They'll do a minute in 30 seconds, that's how fast they are.